# Background Subtraction and Grab Cut

Tags: opencv, image-processing, computer-vision

I have the following two images, one being the background model, and the other with a new foreground object coming into the scene.  I'm trying to isolate the foreground object.  I got some progress with Grab Cut method.  However, it is not perfect and does not run at real time speed (30 fps).  I'm wondering if someone can suggest faster method.  I tried background subtraction and mog2 method but did not get good results (too noisy).

Background: https://i.stack.imgur.com/e45Oo.jpg

Object: https://i.stack.imgur.com/BOkqM.jpg

GrabCut: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Wd834.jpg

Comment: Background subtraction is robust to small  light change, while your situation is unmatched.

Comment: your illumination is aweful... you should invest time in getting a good signal instead of wasting time on trying to process a bad one